# How to pass array by reference in my actual parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

I came across an error when I tried to pass array by reference using int(& a)[5].
   But when I wanna implement it ,we should pass a reference which I initialize as 
          int & refer=*a;
   Following is my code ,and two ways to pass reference and pointer to the calling function  . How to explain that I can't simply pass a reference into it?

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void add(int (&)[5],int );
int main()
 {


int a[5]={5,4,3,2,1};
int len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
cout<<"len="<<len<<endl;
cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;// the name of array is actually the pointer

int& refer=*a;

add(a,len);    //which is correct,we pass a pointer to the calling function;
add(refer,len);   //which is wrong,we pass a reference to the calling function;
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}

return 0;
}



void add(int (&a)[5],int len){
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
   a[i]=a[i]+10;
  }
}
```

Comment: If add only takes an array of size 5, why do you pass the length? You only need `int a[]` to pass an array for modification in a function. In C++ you can use `std::vector<int>&` and take advantage of the fact a vector knows its size.

Comment: Because I wanna know how many times I should loop. When I pass a[] into a calling function, a[] decays to the pointer to the first element.In that sense, I would lose my information about the size of this array,which means I should add the length of my array together.

Comment: @user3570984: With this signature, `a` doesn't decay to pointer, so you know the size (and may remove `int len`).

Comment: But the size is right there, in the function signature!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int& refer=*a;
```

This is not a reference to the array, but to its first element. Try:

```
int (&refer)[5] = a;
add(refer,len);
```

Comment: As for  int (&refer)[5] = a; I don't quite understand why you can assign pointer,like a,to a reference.

Comment: @user3570984: Because `a` *is not* a pointer. It's an array. The expression `a` decays to pointer in certain contexts, essentially where a pointer is expected. Also note that this is not assignment. It's initialization, although expressed with an `=` sign.

Comment: @user3570984 You can have a reference to an array (or a pointer) pretty much the same way as a reference to an integer. The line `int (&refer)[5] = a;` says _" `refer` is a reference to `a`"_.